# How to connect to ProxySQL with default config on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, proxysql

I installed docker, got the most popular box with proxySQL.

```
docker run -d -p 6032:6032 --name proxysql prima/proxysql:latest
```

then I tried to connect to it from my local mysql like so:

```
mysql -u admin -padmin -h 127.0.0.1 -P6032
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"
```

I tried this trick with `twindb/proxysql:latest` and `prima/proxysql:latest` docker images and the result was the same :(

Comment: are you sure about the ports. The Dockerfile for the image doesn't declare any exposed ports and the default config file seems to be using another port.

Comment: 6032 is a default port for proxySQL as it is stated [here](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/ProxySQL-Configuration) and [here](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki). If I specify another port in mySQL connection request, I'm getting `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61 "Connection refused")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map `6033` instead of `6032`

```
docker run -d 6033:6033 --name proxysql prima/proxysql:latest
```

And then run below

```
mysql -u admin -padmin -h 127.0.0.1 -P6033
```

Inside the container mysql listens on `127.0.0.1:6032` and for outside connections it listens on `0.0.0.0:6033`. So you need to use `6033` for connections from outside the container

Comment: Thanks, it moves me further. Now I have different  error saying: `ERROR 1045 (28000): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'admin' (using password: YES)`. And It is clear what to do next. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you want to be able to access the admin configuration database as well, you'll still need to map port `6032`. So in that case I would map both ports, e.g. `-p 6033:6033 -p 6032:6032`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot connect to proxysql from outside the container in default config. bash into the proxysql container and then execute

```
 mysql -u admin -p<password-here> -h 127.0.0.1 -P 6032 --prompt='proxysql>'
```

**default password** will be the **admin**

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I discovered back in the day. Thank you for putting it here.